# Unable to remove margin in material ui appBar and change appearance of menu item when clicked

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am making a content website using react & material ui. Inside the drawer component, I have included an appBar. Everything is working fine. But I want to do slight changes in its appearance and also in functionality. I am unable to do following two things,

1. remove margin around the appBar,
2. change the appearance of the menu button when clicked.

Current status of the page looks like,

[image]

submenu.js

```
import React, {Fragment, useCallback, useState} from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
  appBar: {
    shadowColor: '#206a5d',
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
  },
}));

export function Submenu({items, header}) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

  const clickHandler = useCallback(
    () => {
      setSelected(!selected)
    },
    [selected],
  );


  return (
    <Fragment>
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="sticky"
              color="inherit"
              className={classes.appBar}
              style={{margin: 0}}
      >
        <Typography style={{marginLeft: '1.5rem'}}>
          <h1 style={{color:'#1f4068'}}>{header}</h1>
        </Typography>
        <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
          {items.map(item =>
          <ListItem button
                    dense
                    key={item.title}
                    component={Link}
                    to={item.to || '/404'}
                    style={{padding:'0.25rem',
                      textAlign: 'center',
                    }}
          >
            <ListItemText primary={item.title} />
          </ListItem>
        )}
        </div>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
      </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Technical.js

```
import React, {Fragment} from "react";
import {Submenu} from "../submenu";
import {TechIntro} from "./Introduction";
import {TheDowTheory} from "./DowTheory";
import {Charts} from "./Charts";
import {Trends} from "./Trendlines";
import {Support} from "./Support";
import {Indicators} from "./Indicators";
import {TechRoutes} from "./TechRoutes";
import {makeStyles} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  toolbar: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    // necessary for content to be below app bar
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
  },
}));

const menu = [
  {
    title: 'Introduction',
    to: '/technical',
    component: TechIntro
  },
  {
    title: 'The Dow Theory',
    to: '/thedowtheory',
    component: TheDowTheory
  },
  {
    title: 'Chart Patterns',
    to: '/chart',
    component: Charts
  },
  {
    title: 'Trend Lines',
    to: '/trends',
    component: Trends
  },
  {
    title: 'Support/Resistance',
    to: '/support',
    component: Support
  },
  {
    title: 'Technical Indicators',
    component: Indicators,
    to: '/indicators'
  },
  {
    title: 'Fibonacci',
    component: 'Fibonacci',
    to: '/fibonacci'
  },
  {
    title: 'Risk Management',
    component: 'Risk',
    to: '/risk'
  },
]

export const Technical = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <Fragment>
        <Router>
          <Submenu items={menu} header={'Technical Analysis'} />
          <TechRoutes />
        </Router>
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```

TechRoutes.js

```
import React from "react";
import {Switch, Route, Redirect} from "react-router-dom";
import {TheDowTheory} from "./DowTheory";
import {TechIntro} from "./Introduction";
import {Charts} from "./Charts";
import {Trends} from "./Trendlines";
import {Support} from "./Support";
import {Indicators} from "./Indicators";

export const TechRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/technical" component={TechIntro} />
      <Route path="/thedowtheory" component={TheDowTheory} />
      <Route path="/chart" component={Charts} />
      <Route path="/trends" component={Trends} />
      <Route path="/support" component={Support} />
      <Route path="/indicators" component={Indicators} />
      {/*<Route path="/404" component={NotFound} />*/}
      <Redirect to="/404" />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

Comment: You should create a minimal reproducible example (could be on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/))